# Android progressBar not showing or invisible

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

My custom progress bar doesn't show. I animate it in my activity and also use drawable resource file for it. Here is my code.

Activity.java

```
  ProgressBar progressBar;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
      progressBar =  findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", 
   0, 500); 
    animation.setDuration(5000); // in milliseconds
    animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
```

activity.xml

```
      <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"

    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="500"
    android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.475"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.153" />
```

drawableResource.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="3.8sp" >
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
     </shape>
```

[want this kind of progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlGka.png)

Comment: Code should be posted in text format not images!

Comment: i updated my question ...please go through it now .i am waiting for your solution

Comment: thanks @Khemraj .Can you please go through the question please.I already spent 2 days in it .I am new in stack overflow

Comment: Can you show your required UI?

Comment: @khemraj I added image in my post ...the area in square field there i need my progress bar

Comment: No, I asked what you want reach? Do you want a circular or horizontal progressbar. So can you post an UI image that you are following?

Comment: @khemraj sorry for that .I updated the image can you please check it..

Comment: @Khemraj Are you there ?

Answer (score 0):

**[Here](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)** is exactly what you are looking for.

Add this dependency in your gradle.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1' // or compile for old versions gradle
}
```

in your project level `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

In your layout add this.

```
<com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/donut_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    custom:donut_progress="30"/>
```

for more customization please see [library link](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress).

[image]